# "Either the username or the repository does not exist"

Tags: python, travis-ci

`travis-encrypt OverLordGoldDragon see-rnn`; [repository](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn); `travis-encrypt` version: 1.3.1, Win OS. Seems [cli.py](https://github.com/mandeep/Travis-Encrypt/blob/master/travis/cli.py#L66) looks [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn), which shows build passing - but an error is thrown anyway; full trace below.

Any resolution?

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\travis\encrypt.py", line 49, in retrieve_public_key
    return response.json()['key'].replace(' RSA ', ' ')
KeyError: 'key'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\viz\Scripts\travis-encrypt.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\travis\cli.py", line 68, in cli
    key = retrieve_public_key('{}/{}' .format(username, repository), url)
  File "d:\anaconda\envs\viz\lib\site-packages\travis\encrypt.py", line 52, in retrieve_public_key
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("Either the username: '{}' or the repository: '{}' does not exist. Please enter a valid username or repository name. The username and repository name are both case sensitive." .format(username, repository))
travis.encrypt.InvalidCredentialsError: Either the username: 'OverLordGoldDragon' or the repository: 'see-rnn' does not exist. Please enter a valid username or repository name. The username and repository name are both case sensitive.
```

Comment: is your repository configured correctly? the `README` example works for me

Comment: @gold_cy Travis-tested with 99% coverage; what specifically should be configured? Unsure if setup.py works properly, as that's the exact step I'm on (uploading to test.pypi.org with an encrypted API key) - but adding path to local repository's `.travis.yml` yields the same error

Comment: sorry i’m not a Travis expert however, if look at what the repository returns in the README it’s an XML whereas yours returns a picture of a badge

Comment: @gold_cy Maybe that's just how it works - do you have an example of a repository whose README displays fully on that site? I checked several that are registered with PyPi, they also show only a build badge

Comment: I meant the README of `Travis-Encrypt`. Take a look at their page in Travis, looks different than yours -->https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/mandeep/Travis-Encrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use below via the [travis client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#windows), taken from [Travis PyPi deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pypi/):

```
travis encrypt token-name --add deploy.password --com
```

Resolution via `travis-encrypt` can be followed in [this Issue](https://github.com/mandeep/Travis-Encrypt/issues/24).